# Trouble scaling image in css

Tags: html, css

I want a particular picture to cover the entire background of my site and when the window is resized, I want the picture to be scaled accordingly. What I'm looking for is something like https://www.tumblr.com. Notice the picture in the background scales accordingly to the window size.

Here is my css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#backdrop {
  z-index: -999;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Where `#backdrop` is the id for the image I'm using.

I've tried numerous things but nothing seems to change the way my image is displayed.

Comment: have you tried media queries.?

Comment: It's generally easier and more appropriate to use an image as a background  on an element and not as an image tag. Look into `background-size: cover` for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to let an `img` behave like a `background-image`. See this working example:

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1100/300">
```

Comment: `object-fit: cover;`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes, https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit for when using background-image is not an option.

Comment: Boss, this is not a right thing. I guess this is mainly for `flex` boxes, not for all the cases?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I edited the post, added a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- Change the `height: auto;` to `height: 100%`, and add `background` styles.

  ```css
  #backdrop {
    z-index: -999;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url("image.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  ```
- Also, use a HTML 5 Doctype:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  ```